# Activeprinter should change but doesn't

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I'm a bit confused that ActivePrinter doesn't really do what I expect to do.

The objective:
I want some pdf files and a worksheet to be printed at a different printer than my default printer. And afterwards make sure that the default printer is again the ActivePrinter

- The defaultprinter : "HP5C4FAD (HP OfficeJet Pro 7740 series) on Ne06:"
- the printer I want to print to `Sec_Printer`: "Kyocera ECOSYS M5521cdw on Ne05:"

The codes I have:

This is the function code for printing pdf's from my PC:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function PrintThisDoc(formname As Long, FileName As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim X As Long
X = ShellExecute(formname, "Print", FileName, 0&, 0&, 0)
End Function
```

And this is the sub code I use to print:

```
Dim CurrentPrinter, Sec_Printer As String
Sec_Printer = Worksheets("Setup").Range("B1").Value
CurrentPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter
Application.ActivePrinter = Sec_Printer

Dim printThis
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
For j = 0 To aantal - 1
    strDir = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\PVAP Dropbox\ConsultDocs\"
    strFile = Huiswerk_Blad(j) & ".pdf"
    printThis = PrintThisDoc(0, strDir & "\" & strFile)
    Next j
    
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Worksheets("Sec_Afspraak").PrintOut
Application.ActivePrinter = CurrentPrinter
Unload Me
```

`Huiswerk_Blad` is an array with the names of the pdf's that have to be printed
`aantal` is the number of elements in that array

Now the strange thing is, the excelsheet gets printed on the printer I want, the PDF's don't (they are printed on the default printer).
I think that the function for the PDF's doesn't use ActivePrinter because I don't have any other explanation for it... I dind't wrote that function myself, but I can't find where I found that function on the internet. If you need any further information tell me.

Comment: `Application.Activeprinter` naturally sets the printer for Excel, not any other application. You could use something like `CreateObject("WScript.network").setdefaultprinter printer_name`

Comment: @Rory that seems to work. Only it takes a very long time to change the default printer (15sec) so it's not that performance oriented. Is it normal to take so long? Any ideas if it can be easily fixed?